# MySQL restores data

Tags: mysql, restore

Sometimes mysql restores data - I update a row and after half an hour everything is as it was before. It is very strange...

Maybe it has something to do with the temp-files?

Comment: or perhaps transactions that get rolled back because you didn't commit them. mysql won't "restore" data on its own

Comment: i use MyISAM. So there are no transactions.

Comment: You'll have to provide more information about your system and configuration. Is this a hosted service? Self-hosted? VPS?

Comment: It is self-hosted (virtual Server). The Table has 4703 rows at the moment.

Comment: i found the option --myisam-recover (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html).
it is set to "BACKUP".

Comment: And is your engine crashing, being marked as dirty, and being brought back online every 3o minutes?  If not, I doubt that's your problem.

Comment: Turn on the [general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html)